# Get parameters that came from HREF property in TabContainer Dojo

Tags: parameters, tabs, dojo, lazy-loading

I have started to use the TabContainer in DOJO, but I am working with dynamic tabs and dynamic contents. For generate my TABs, I access a REST which give me JSON data with each tab name.

After, when the user to click in a specifies tab I need call another REST for take the information to tab's container. The default "lazy" load when you are using the HREF property, is perfect for me, because, I can't load all contents at first moment... And I also need to pass parameters to another file(teste.html?idTable=123).

When I access the file teste.html?idTable=123 directly by the browser I can catch the parameter, but when I use HREF property, it not works.

How can I get the parameters that came from HREF property?
Is there another better way for to make this?(I need lazy load)

Main.js

data.table is a JSON...

```
var tc = new TabContainer({
   style: "height: 100%; width: 100%;"
}, "tc1-prog");

for(var i=0; i<data.table.length; i++){

   var cp = new ContentPane({

      id: data.table[i].id,
      title: data.table[i].name,
      //content: "teste - "+i
      href: 'tables/teste.html?idTable='+data.table[i].id

   });

   tc.addChild(cp);

}

tc.startup();
```

teste.html

```
require([
   'dojo/io-query',
   'dojo/domReady!'
], function (ioQuery) {

   var uri = window.location.search;
   //var uri = "http://some.server.org/somecontext/?foo=bar&foo=bar2&bit=byte";
   var query = uri.substring(uri.indexOf("?") + 1, uri.length);
   var queryObject = ioQuery.queryToObject(query);

   console.log('idTable: ', queryObject.idTable);

});
```

Comment: I discovered that my javascript is not running, only if I access directly by browser. Is there any property which I can say that the javascript code must to be executed?

Comment: I wanted to say javascript code in "remote" file(teste.html)

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have access to the backend. I can just access REST, that returns me a JSON. I can make/change only the frontend. I think it is an useful info.

Comment: "If you need to execute JavaScript inside your content panes, use dojox/layout/ContentPane instead of dijit/layout/ContentPane and set executeScripts=”true”."

Comment: I have just tested with dojox/layout/ContentPane. But it is impossible get the parameters, even running javascript in remote file. Other strange behavior is, when I click others tabs, the ContentPane does not calls again the remote file.